# Android sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23 not found

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I've been using the following command to install abi until today.

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23
```

But now I got the following error.

```
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23'
Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
```

Is anyone having the same issue? I'm using Android SDK r24.4.1.

Comment: Same issue here. I can't seem to find a way for installing ABIs at all now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue about this:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206022

EDIT:
Working again

EDIT2: As of 2016-11-29, the problem remains:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23                                       15:59:01  ☁  feat/TravisArchitecture ☀
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
  Validate XML
  Parse XML
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23'
Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
```

Comment: Yup, I confirmed as well.

Comment: EDIT2: As of 2016-11-29, the problem remains: still facing same error any update on it ?