# sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23 is missing from the repository

Tags: android

I've been using the following command "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23" and it works but suddenly stopped working somewhere in the last week.

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23
```

It seems the package is removed from the repository.

```
 ubuntu@5f11aa31372c:~$ android list sdk --extended --all | grep sys-img- armeabi-v7a-android | grep -v wear | grep -v tv
 id: 62 or "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-24"
 id: 82 or "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22"
 id: 92 or "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-21"
 id: 100 or "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-19"
 id: 104 or "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-18"
 id: 108 or "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-17"
 id: 113 or "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-16"
 id: 118 or "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-15"
 id: 123 or "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-14"
 id: 124 or "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-10"
```

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Note: I've posted the same question in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228113&thanks=228113&ts=1479517484 but haven't got any responses yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-XX not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466682/android-sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-xx-not-found)